# Is there a value of $\alpha$ such that $\cot\alpha=-2\sqrt{3}\sin\alpha?$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a value of $\alpha$ such that $\cot\alpha=-2\sqrt{3}\sin\alpha?$

How can I think to solve the problem? We can find that $\dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cot\alpha}=-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}},$ so $\sin\alpha$ and $\cot\alpha$ should be with different signs. I looked at the trig ratio table and saw that $\dfrac{\sin150^\circ}{\cot150^\circ}=-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}},$ but I really don't like that solution. Can you come up with something better?

What if we have the following problem:
Is there a value of $\alpha$ such that $2\tan\alpha=-\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$\cos(\alpha)=-2\sqrt{3}\sin^2{\alpha}=-2\sqrt{3}(1-\cos^2{\alpha})$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't see why $\cos\alpha=-2\sqrt{3}\sin^2\alpha.$ Can you clarify that for me?

Comment: It comes from the formula $\tan={\sin\over\cos}$ and that $\cot={1\over \tan}$

Comment: @nicoledobreva - Write cot($\alpha$) = cos($\alpha$)/sin($\alpha$).

Comment: Thank you! I saw why $\cos\alpha=-2\sqrt{3}(1-\cos^2\alpha),$ but I don't see how this helps for the solution. How from here can we say if there is a value for $\alpha$?

Comment: It is a quadratic equation of the variable $\cos(\alpha)$. You can use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Oh, I see thank you! I have just one more question. Here we used the identity $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1.$ Doesn't it hold only if there is a value for $\alpha$ which is what we need to check?

Comment: You can think of it this way: If we assume there is a value then we do the above to see if we can find the value or find out there is a contradiction. If we find a contradiction then that means there is no value.

Answer (score 1):

$\cot\alpha = \frac{\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}=-2\sqrt{3}\sin\alpha$ is equivalent to $\cos \alpha = -2\sqrt{3}\sin ^2 \alpha$ and so to $$\cos \alpha = -2\sqrt{3} (1-\cos ^2 \alpha)$$

If we note $X = \cos \alpha$, then $$2\sqrt{3} X^2 -X -2\sqrt{3}=0$$

The discriminant is $\Delta = 49>0$.

So the solutions of the polynomial equations are $x_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm7}{4\sqrt{3}}$ and $x_2 = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is the only one that is inferior to $1$ in absolute value (this is important because $\forall \alpha, |\cos \alpha | \leqslant 1$)

So there is only one solution to your equation, which are $\alpha = \pm \cos ^{-1} -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} +2k\pi$ so $$\alpha = \pm \frac{5\pi}{6} + 2k\pi$$

Comment: In fact. thank you. I edited

Comment: Okay the solutions are $-\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and $\dfrac{2\sqrt3}{3}.$ What should I do next? I don't understand what you have noted: "which are both inferior to $1$ in absolute value".

Comment: the thing is since $|\cos|<1$ if the roots had been superior to $1$ in absolute values, there would have been no solution despite the fact that the polynomial equation had solutions

Comment: I think it would be better if you wrote $|\cos\alpha|\le1$.

Comment: for a reason I don't understand, i can't edit my comment, but I edited my answer.

Comment: Also, I think that the positive root $\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$ is greater than $1.$

Comment: Sorry (again). I edited. This time I think it's right.